# Cannot allocate or assign NSArray during UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, segue, ios5.1

It seems my viewcontroller i'm creating during the segue cannot modify or create any member variable that is type NSArray. I can create local variables within any function I please but assigning a membervariable doesn't work nor does allocating the array in the init instead.

What the heck is going on?

This would work if not using iOS5.1 and Xcode 4.3 I'm certain.

```
- (id)initWithViewControllers:(NSArray *)newViewControllers
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _viewControllers = [newViewControllers retain];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The member variables are all setup correctly. It simply doesn't assign _viewControllers anything. it is always nil.

I cannot include the entire code but essentially it is such:

A root navigation controller is used to load a table view controller to pick from two rows. Each row then pushes another view controller to load where we do some work. The failure is happening when I tap the row and allocate another view controller. During that allocation the member variable of type NSMutableArray or NSArray do not get created they always return 0x0. I can't set the variable either by creating my own initWithArray:(NSArray *).

Please don't down vote this if it's missing something the question is valid and can be modified. Just post a comment and I will answer. I've never seen Obj-C behave this way ever is why I'm posting this.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and the exact problem? (Xcode error or printout of unexpected result)

Comment: Where are you trying to *use* this instance variable that you're seeing it as nil? That's more likely to be your problem.

Comment: It ended up being an issue with a corrupt png... weird side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want NSMutableArray?

Comment: No they don't allocate any NSArray. NSMutableArray is an NSArray

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. UX team supplied png's that resolve to have no height or infinite height. They show up as png with no alpha channel. I have no idea how this is the side effect but I fixed the issue where the array wouldn't get assigned to by using my own png files and it resolved the issue.

Again, I have no clue as to how this caused this to ripple through the app.